# Contract verification. How can I check contract already verified or not (with code)?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

### I use:

```
await hre.run("verify:verify", {
        address: CONTRACT.address,
        constructorArguments: [ARGUMENT]
    });
```

---

but sometimes it returns: **Reason: Already Verified**

I want to write `if statement` , but I don't know how to check if contract already verified or not.

For example:

```
if (!contract.alreadyVerified){
await hre.run("verify:verify", {
            address: CONTRACT.address,
            constructorArguments: [ARGUMENT]
        });
}
```